# Something's eating my plants

Tags: plant-recommendations

We live in an apartment with a back patio. Something has devoured our chives, kale, spinach and taken chunks of branches out of our tomato plant. Anyone know what would be so brave as to come into an apartment complex???

Comment: what part of the world are you in - and what floor are you on?

Comment: We are in North Central Florida. So, South Eastern united states. We are on ground floor.

Comment: @user21409 Could you see if you can get a picture of any bite marks? For this moment I am thinking mouse or rat.

Comment: Ground floor, when its quiet at night, all sorts of creatures will be prowling around... suggest you keep a watch at night, or go out with a torch periodically. Even better if you can run a camera all night and watch the footage....

Comment: Do you have close-up pictures where we see how vegetables were severed?